# Errors while saving Spark Dataframe to Hbase using Apache Phoenix

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm trying to save jsonRDD into hbase using [apache phoenix spark plugin](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html) : `df.saveToPhoenix(tableName, zkUrl = Some(quorumAddress))`. The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
  ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  NAME VARCHAR,
  SURNAME VARCHAR) SALT_BUCKETS = 40, COMPRESSION='GZ';
```

I have about 100,000 - 2,000,000 records in this kind of tables. Some of them are saved normally. But some of them fail with error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: 
callTimeout=1200000, callDuration=2902566: row 'PERSON' on table 'SYSTEM.CATALOG' at
region=SYSTEM.CATALOG,,1443172839381.a593d4dbac97863f897bca469e8bac66.,
hostname=hadoop-02,16020,1443292360474, seqNum=339
at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixRecordWriter.close(PhoenixRecordWriter.java:62)

at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$5.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1043)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1294)
```

What could that mean? Are there any other ways to bulk insert data from DataFrame to hbase?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I guess i've cleaned and reduced amount of data.